# What happens to me Salary requirement for Dutch knowledge migrant once I turn 30?

Tags: resident-permit, netherlands

I am 29 years old and I am working in the Netherlands as a knowledge migrant and my current salary satisfies the salary requirement for the below 30 criteria. I have a residence permit valid until 2020. I will be turing 30 soon, so should my salary satisfy the above 30 requirement for my current residence permit to be valid?

Comment: You could post your edit as answer as it seems to fully address your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got a Reply from the IND after a long time. The jist is if I remain with the same company it does not matter, I have to just maintain the below 30 salary requirement even after i turn 30. But if i change companies after turning 30 then i have to satisfy the above 30 requirement.